# SQL Server : returning multiple rows by ROWID by using only one where / LIKE OPERATOR

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

Here are rows in my database which I want to get:

[image]

I want to get get all 3 rows by executing one query, this ids are received as procedure parameters, sometimes I can receive 1 id and sometimes I can receive 10 of them, depends what users sends to database.

I wrote something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products
WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ProductId) LIKE '%' + 'A9472294-CFDD-40AC-BC2D-00E39AF4A300, 9A817E40-E4B1-4487-A376-010DD6377E38, 078A3C75-C442-4D88-A1E0-0118B8706667' + '%'

SELECT * 
FROM Products
WHERE 'A9472294-CFDD-40AC-BC2D-00E39AF4A300, 9A817E40-E4B1-4487-A376-010DD6377E38, 078A3C75-C442-4D88-A1E0-0118B8706667' LIKE '%' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ProductId) + '%'
```

How come the second example returns rows as expected and the first example does not return any rows?

The definition says: `%or% finds any values that have "or" in any position`

How does this actually work? Could anyone explain?

EDIT:

I thought this LIKE operator should be used on my column like

Select *
From Products
Where ProductId Like '%' + 'SomeStringId' + '%';

because LIKE operator is used in a WHERE clause to search for a specified pattern in a column and my column is `ProductId` so I can't understand how come example like this works:

Select *
From Products
Where 'SomeStringId' Like '%' + ProductId + '%';

How come this example above works if Like is not used on my column, it's used on some string acctually...

Comment: in your first LIKE statement you are looking for the entire string with commas and it wont match the full string of all them combined.  You cant do a LIKE with multiple values in a comma string, anything between the single quote is compareing to that entire string

Comment: You'd probably be better off using `WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ProductID) IN ('A9472294-CFDD-40AC-BC2D-00E39AF4A300', '9A817E40-E4B1-4487-A376-010DD6377E38', '078A3C75-C442-4D88-A1E0-0118B8706667')`

Comment: and how are you getting the multiple values to your SP?  As a single string comma delimited or as multiple paramaters?  You need to parse it out into a temp table or multiple strings and do a like statement using those

Comment: @Brad gettting as a string comma delimited as in my example, and how come second query works?

Comment: adding to Steves above if you get comma seperated list, turn into a table variable or temp table and use an IN like he described on the data that is coverted into a table, that way it wont matter how many are sent it will look for all of them

Comment: The way you are doing this is going to be slow-- you want to convert your input to GUID to match the DB not convert the DB data to a string.  Remember a GUID is stored as a number so any of these conversions are going to be very very slow.

Comment: Your second one works because you are comparing a single value in the table to the long string with all 3 values in it.  So you will find the single value in your long list of strings

Comment: Going to the underlying problem there are better ways to do this see https://stackoverflow.com/q/337704

Comment: @Brad Well I don't understand LIKE operator really well, this confuses me, I thought The LIKE operator is used in a WHERE clause to search for a specified pattern in a column so that means I should says MyColumn Like '%something%' and in my example I said : SOMELARGESTRING LIKE '%mycolumn%' .. and how come it returns rows from my table as expected?

Comment: Basically, the point is that in the first query, you are comparing `ProductID` to `%A9472294-CFDD-40AC-BC2D-00E39AF4A300, 9A817E40-E4B1-4487-A376-010DD6377E38, 078A3C75-C442-4D88-A1E0-0118B8706667%` which means that unless `ProductID` has the exact match for the string between the `%`s, you will not get any results.  However, the second query takes the long string and checks to see if `%ProductID%` exists within that string.

Comment: @Steve-o169 check for my Edit, I understand it, but I'm not sure how come this works, so if ProductId exist in long string it will return row with that ProductId obliviously but I am little bit confused it works like that.. I thought LIKE must be used on my column like ProductId like .. something.. check for my edit please...

Comment: `LIKE` can be used to compare any string to any other string, whether it be string like column, column like string, column like column, string like string, column like string+column, string like string+column, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You should split the string and then use an inner join.

For SQL Server below 2016 with the cumbersome string split via XML:

```
SELECT p.*
       FROM products p
            INNER JOIN (SELECT arg_xml_node.xml_node.value('(.)[1]', 'uniqueidentifier') uniqueidenfier
                               FROM (SELECT convert(xml,
                                            concat('<x>',
                                                   replace('A9472294-CFDD-40AC-BC2D-00E39AF4A300, 9A817E40-E4B1-4487-A376-010DD6377E38, 078A3C75-C442-4D88-A1E0-0118B8706667',
                                                           ', ',
                                                           '</x><x>'),
                                                   '</x>')) xml) arg_xml
                                    CROSS APPLY arg_xml.xml.nodes('x') arg_xml_node (xml_node)) arg_uniqueidenfier
                       ON arg_uniqueidenfier.uniqueidenfier = p.productid;
```

For SQL Server 2016 and above with the elegant way using `string_split()`:

```
SELECT p.*
       FROM products p
            INNER JOIN (SELECT convert(uniqueidentifier, ltrim(value)) uniqueidenfier
                               FROM string_split('A9472294-CFDD-40AC-BC2D-00E39AF4A300, 9A817E40-E4B1-4487-A376-010DD6377E38, 078A3C75-C442-4D88-A1E0-0118B8706667',
                                                 ',')) arg_uniqueidenfier
                       ON arg_uniqueidenfier.uniqueidenfier = p.productid;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=519bfd2a87f8f454afb5efffb8414595)

Comment: check for my edit please, I was little bit confused about LIKE there, I couldnt understand that I can use like on my string like myString like '%MyDatabaseId%' and I get rows from db, I thought Like works on my databse column like '%MyDatabaseId%' LIKE myString